# active bannerApplicationLink and Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

In my application I am using the applicationlayout control from the extension library with bootstrap theme enabled

For the links in the navbar I have set up pagetreenode elements. However when I open a link they do not get the active class.

How can I establish this?

I also wonder if the active class i available in the bootstrap theme?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277632/how-to-set-xpages-navigation-bar-bootstrap-basic-leaf-nodes-to-active/34288043#34288043

Answer (score 0):

From a Bootstrap CSS perspective you need to add "active" as the style class to the active list item (that already has the style class menu-item).

Unfortunately I don't see a way to control this via the extension library Bootstrap configuration. Setting `styleClass` to "active" or setting `selected` to true does not change the output at all.

Possible options include:

1. Create your own renderer (urgh!)
2. Add the active style class using clientside JS
3. Wait for IBM to update the extension library :-)